# I need some help with this derivative problem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is  continuous at $x_0=2$ and
$\lim \frac{f(x)+x}{(x-2)}=3$ as $x\to2$.
Show that $f^{\prime}(2)=-1$.

Comment: I find that f’(2)=2 and not -1

Comment: I think that it can be useful http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: i take f’(2)= lim (f(x)-f(2))/(x-2) = lim ((x-2)k(x) -x -f(2))/(x-2) = lim (x-2)(k(x)-1)/(x-2) = lim (k(x)-1) as x->2 = k(2)-1=3-1=2 and not -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to2}(x-2)$ to get
$$\lim_{x\to2}\Big(f(x)+x\Big)=0$$
$$\implies f(2)=-2$$
Can you use this in your original equation, and get your answer now?

**NOTE**: If you edit and provide context and/or your work, I will provide you the whole solution. This *is* the policy of MathSE.

Comment: I face a problem with my pc’s keyword and I can’t post it correctly. I tried to upload a photo with my answer and it doesn’t allow me because I need at least 10 reputation to post images . Is there any other way to post my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

This is my “answer”.
Firstly I found $f(2)=-2$ then I supposed that $k(x)= \frac{f(x)+x}{x-2}$ and then
$$f’(2)= \lim_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}$$
$$ = \lim_{x\to2} \frac{(x-2)k(x) -x -f(2)}{x-2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(x-2)(k(x)-1)}{x-2} = \lim_{x\to2} (k(x)-1)$$ which equals $k(2)-1=3-1=2$ and not $-1$.

Comment: And I believe you're right. For example, the function $f(x) = 2x-6$ satisfies the assumptions and yet $f'(2)=2$.

Comment: This is correct!, and now you must accept an answer to complete this question here.